# Unknown table in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build what appears to be a fairly simple nested query, but when I combine the following two working queries I'm getting the following error:

**Unknown table 'cm' in field list 
ErrorNr. = 1109.**

```
SELECT `cm`.`cans_id`   AS `cans_id`,
       `cm`.`cans_date` AS `cans_date`, 
       `cm`.`begintfin` AS `begIntFin`, 
       `c`.`cans_id`    AS `CAN_ID`, 
       `c`.`q001`       AS `q001`, 
       `c`.`q002`       AS `q002`, 
       `c`.`q093`       AS `q093`,
       `c`.`q094`       AS `q094`,
       `c`.`mru`        AS `mru2`,
       (SELECT Count(0) AS `count(*)`
        FROM   `cans2notes` `nt`
               JOIN `cans2meta` `cm`
                 ON `cm`.`cans_id` = `nt`.`cans_id`
               JOIN `cans2surveys` `c`
                 ON `c`.`cans_id` = `cm`.`cans_id`
        WHERE  ( `nt`.`cans_id` = `c`.`cans_id` ));
```

Any ideas on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your derived table is missing the `FROM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to a table, but there is no FROM or WHERE clause.

Basically you have

```
select col,
       col,
       col,
       col,
       (select count(*) from sometable)
```

But you don't have a

```
 FROM table cm
 INNER JOIN table c
 ON CM.ID = C.OTHER_ID
```

I'm guessing what you are trying to do is this:

```
SELECT `cm`.`cans_id`   AS `cans_id`,
       `cm`.`cans_date` AS `cans_date`, 
       `cm`.`begintfin` AS `begIntFin`, 
       `c`.`cans_id`    AS `CAN_ID`, 
       `c`.`q001`       AS `q001`, 
       `c`.`q002`       AS `q002`, 
       `c`.`q093`       AS `q093`,
       `c`.`q094`       AS `q094`,
       `c`.`mru`        AS `mru2`,
       `count(*)`       AS 'count'
        FROM   `cans2notes` `nt`
               JOIN `cans2meta` `cm`
                 ON `cm`.`cans_id` = `nt`.`cans_id`
               JOIN `cans2surveys` `c`
                 ON `c`.`cans_id` = `cm`.`cans_id`
        WHERE  ( `nt`.`cans_id` = `c`.`cans_id` )
        GROUP BY `cm`.`cans_id`,
       `cm`.`cans_date`, 
       `cm`.`begintfin`, 
       `c`.`cans_id`, 
       `c`.`q001`, 
       `c`.`q002`, 
       `c`.`q093`,
       `c`.`q094`,
       `c`.`mru`;
```